# In Apex Controllers what is the correct short form way of overriding set; on a variable?

Tags: apex, controller

I know the long hand way of doing this is as follows:

```
private String var1;

public String getvar1() {
 return var1;
}
public void setvar1(String str) {
 var1 = 'Prefix '+str;
}
```

The shorthand way is something along the lines of the following but I don't know how the value is passed:

```
public String var1 {
 get;
 set(String str) {
  this = 'Prefix '+str;
 }
}
```

As such the set is pseudocode. I would like to know the correct form for this shorthand way of writing the setter.

Comment: Refer here...possible duplicate of http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4464/how-to-rewrite-getter-setter-in-different-notation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do.

```
public String var1 {
 get;
 set {
  var1 = value; 
 }
}
```

You can use 'value', which has the actual input for the setter.

This is clearly described in [the documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_properties.htm)

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. I cannot mark this as the answer for another 8 minutes.